# Pushwoosh Push Notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I am trying to use Pushwoosh plugin `pushwoosh-cordova-plugin`.
I followed the documentation given [here](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap)

I am trying to register a mobile device through my backend service. i.e. is by using `/registerDevice` API

So my question is:

1) Do we need the following piece of code? What it exactly do?

```
pushwoosh.onDeviceReady({
appid: "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID",
projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER",
serviceName: "MPNS_SERVICE_NAME"
});
```

2) Can we only have the following piece of code and receive mobile push notification from my notification provider i.e. Pushwoosh ?

```
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
var notification = event.notification;
// handle push open here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need this code to register your app and to recieve notifications from pushwoosh service. you can get all this details 1.appid from pushwoosh account 2. projectid from google api console

```
pushwoosh.onDeviceReady({
appid: "7BCF0-9F***",
projectid: "102568298****",
serviceName: "APPNAME"
});
```